# Shipping = Quantity Weight Simplecart

Tags: javascript, e-commerce, shopping-cart

Hello my name is Mirella and I'm Italian. Excuse me as I write because I use the Google translator. 
Use Simplecart but I have problems with shipping costs. 
My client has different shipping costs. The site will sell bottles of wine of different weights. 
This is the function that I created using your help but I do perform multiplication between weight and quantity. It does not work
Ok. Sorry but it is the first time I write on this site and do not know good English.

```
me.shipping = function()
{ 
    var q = 0; 
    q += item.weight*item.quantity; 

    if(q <= 3000){ 
        return 19.00; 
    } 
    if((q >= 10000)) { 
        return 23.00; 
    } 
    if((q <= 20000)){ 
        return 24.00; 
    } 
    if((q <= 30000)){ 
        return 26.00; 
    } 
    if((q <= 50000)){ 
        return 32.00; 
    } 
    if((q <= 75000)){ 
        return 35.00; 
    } 
    if((q <= 100000)){ 
        return 39.00; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Can you markup the code in this? It's very hard to read the way you've formatted it so far

Comment: Another thing: how can I put the total weight of the bottles in the basket? Which class should I use?

Answer (score 1):

```
if((q >= 10000)) { 
    return 23.00; 
}
```

This line means that all the lines below it will never run

All of your weight checks should use **<=** not >=

eg.

```
if (q <= 100)
  // less than 100

if (q <= 200)
  // 101 to 200

if (q <= 300)
  // 201 to 300
```

etc.

you can finish with

```
else
 // more than 300
```

Comment: For insert the function in my cart, using class SHIPPINGCOST? Is possible insert total weight? Is possible?

Comment: Yes, if you remove `var q=0;` and put it outside the function. Remember to reset it between transactions.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it would be nice if you formatted your question - especially the code. Makes it more readable.

You could almost halve your code by doing this;

```
if(q <= 3000){ 
    return 19.00; 
}
if(q <= 10000){ 
    return 23.00;
} 
if(q <= 20000){ 
    return 24.00; 
} 
// ... and so on
```

Perhaps the real problem will become a bit clearer then :-)

Comment: Ok. Sorry but it is the first time I write on this site and do not know good English.

Comment: No problem! Welcome to the site and don't worry about the English - it's fine

Comment: dear, tanks! Insert the function in my cart user class SHIPPINGCOAST? No watch SHIPPING!!! Is possible insert total weight in my cart?

Answer (score 0):

Function for different shipping. 
Problem var **Q** for weight. Weight X Quantity = Total Weight. Is correcty script?

```
me.shipping = function()
    { 
        var q = 0; 
        q += item.weight*item.quantity;

    if(q <= 3000){ 
        return 19.00; 
    } 
    if((q >= 10000)) { 
        return 23.00; 
    } 
    if((q <= 20000)){ 
        return 24.00; 
    } 
    if((q <= 30000)){ 
        return 26.00; 
    } 
    if((q <= 50000)){ 
        return 32.00; 
    } 
    if((q <= 75000)){ 
        return 35.00; 
    } 
    if((q <= 100000)){ 
        return 39.00; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I think `if((q >= 10000))` should use `<=` too. But it should be an edit to the question, not an answer.